# Showing the textfield directly above keyboard when editing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard, textfield

I would like to try and make the text field appear above the keyboard when in editing mode, as shown in this picture, which is in the app Clash of Clans:

[image]

Is this achievable through some code or doing stuff in the Interface Builder, or have Supercell (makers of Clash of Clans) done this themselves?

Comment: yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the `inputAccessoryView`.

As it says [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview):

> This property is typically used to attach an accessory view to the system-supplied keyboard that is presented for UITextField and UITextView objects.

You add the `inputAccessoryView` to the individual `UITextField` and `UITextView` views you have on your page, meaning that you can have separate `inputAccessoryView`s for the various textfields if so desired.

So in your case you would need to create your own view containing a `UITextField` and that checkmark button you have on the right and then add that view as a `inputAccessoryView` to your textfields and then it should appear right above your keyboard.

Hope that is enough to get you started, now you at least know that you should search for `inputAccessoryView` to see what can be done :)